# How to add external my.cnf file to Percona server in Docker?

Tags: docker, percona, my.cnf

I have created docker container with Percona executing this command:

```
docker run -v <path-to-files-on-host-machine>:/etc/mysql/conf.d 
--name percona -p 6604:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345 -d percona/percona-server:latest \
    --innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend:max:1G --sql_mode='' --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_general_ci;
```

According to [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/percona/) on DockerHub I have mount directory with `my.cnf` in my host machine as `/etc/mysql/conf.d` in Docker container.

But when I start my container Percona doesn't read settings from my custom `my.cnf`. Also I tried to create `my.cnf` with errors to crash Percona on start. But no effect.

How can I attach custom `my.cnf` to Percona Docker container?

Comment: are you running with SELinux enabled?

Comment: I don't know. But I tried on different host systems: Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: ok, so exec into the container and check if you're files are where you expect them to be

Comment: When I go to container: `docker exec -u root -it percona /bin/bash` , and `cat /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf` I get contents of `my.cnf` on the host machine

Comment: no clue then, sorry, check that the included `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` includes the dirs, but can't see why it wouldn't... as a workaround you can try to just mount your file as `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and hide the one provided... but that's a hack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem in this way:

- start container with attached STDIN: `docker start -i percona`
- it was error in output: Warning: `World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf' is ignored`

So `my.cnf` had wrong permissions. 
I solved it that way: `chmod 755 /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf`